# How to exclude some directories and files from deliting in Delete Files task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to delete all files from `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` (it is so called "a" folder in the appropriate build agent's folder, click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to read more about predefined variables in azure pipelines). I also know that [Delete Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops) uses the [minimatch patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts).

The inner structure of my `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`:

```
a
|--Client
|       |--ImportantFolder
|       |                |--FileNumber1
|       |                |--....(Many other files here)
|       |                |--FileNumberN
|       |--OtherJunkFolder
|       |--OtherFile
|--JunkFolder
```

So, the folder `a` has two subfolders (`Client` and `JunkFolder`), the `Client` folder has one folder named `ImportantFolder`, one folder named `OtherJunkFolder` and one file named `OtherFile`. `ImportantFolder` has the many files with different names and extensions.

How can I delete all folders and files from the folder `a` except those in folders `Client/ImportantFolders`? In other words: I want to do something like this:

```
**
!Client/ImportantFolder/**
```

But this pattern delete everything from the folder `a`. I also tried

```
**
!(Client/**)
```

and just

```
**
!(Client)
```

Both didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing, pattern `!(Client)` works. But it also keeps the `OtherJunkFolder` and `OtherFile` in folder Client.

Pattern `!(Client/ImportantFolder)` does not work.

As workaround you can use a script task to delete all folders and files from the folder except those in folders Client/ImportantFolders. Please check below powershell script in a powershell task.

```
Get-ChildItem "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)" | where { $_.Name -inotmatch "Client" } | Remove-Item -Recurse
Get-ChildItem "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/Client" | where { $_.Name -inotmatch "ImportantFolder" } | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

Another possible workaround is the use a copy file task to copy the folder `Client/ImportantFolder` to a new folder. For below example, folder `Client/ImportantFolder` will be copied to a new folder `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/a1` . And then point the following tasks to this new folder.

[image]

If your intention is to only include folder `Client/ImportantFolder` in your artifacts to be published in the following publish build artifacts task. The easiest way is to point `Path to publish` to folder `Client/ImportantFolder`. Then the artifacts published will only have folder `Client/ImportantFolder`. Check below example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try without `**` and only with `!(Client)`, it will remove the `JunkFolder` except the `Client` folder.

You can do `Client/ImportantFolder`, I don't know why, I guess because the delete look on the `a` folder and not deeper.