# TFS include files and folders within the Delete Files Task

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, pattern-matching, tfsbuild

I need to use the 'Delete files' task in a VNext build definition (TFS 2018). after 'Publish Artifact' task I am using the 'Delete File' task to delete all the files and folder in the drop folder but except the below ones and used the pattern like in Contents section

```
!bin/
!Views/
!Scripts/
!Content/
!Reports/
!Web.config
```

[image]

I found that we can use exclusion pattern, but it's not working. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Delete Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops) uses the minimatch patterns.

> **Q: What's a minimatch pattern? How does it work?** A: See:
>
> - https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch
> - https://realguess.net/tags/minimatch/
> - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html

Thus, you could use `!(bin)`, it will remove other folders except the `bin` folder.

For Web.config it should be `!(Web.config)`

If this still not work, you could use a copy file task to copy the folder as workaround. Details please refer Levi Lu's reply in this question: [How to exclude some directories and files from deliting in Delete Files task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60546946/how-to-exclude-some-directories-and-files-from-deliting-in-delete-files-task)

For multiple folder you can write

```
!(bin|views)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried !(bin), this works, when i tried another folder like 
!(bin) ,
!(Views)
this tasks will also remove bin folder, as my requirement is to keep the 2 folders only and delete reset of other files and folder?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  I tried !(bin), this works, when i tried another folder like !(bin) , !(Views) this tasks will also remove bin folder, as my requirement is to keep only 2 folders only and delete reset of other files and folder?

Comment: Hi@SaadAwan Try to use this format `!(bin|Views)`,check if this do the trick.